# Getting `ld: warning: directory not found for option` due to space in directory name

Tags: xcode, macos

The directory of my project is the following, and as such I've set the Library Search Paths to it:

```
/Users/andrew/Google Drive/Denarri/Dev/Denarri-iOS
```

Because it has a space in the directory name, I entered it into the Library Search Paths like this:

```
/Users/andrew/Google\ Drive/Denarri/Dev/Denarri-iOS
```

No matter which way I enter it, it gives me this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/andrew/Google'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FDrive/Denarri/Dev/Denarri-iOS'
```

It appears that it's seeing it as two separate directories based on where the backslash is. How can I set this correctly?

Comment: Try `/Users/andrew/"Google Drive"/Denarri/Dev/Denarri-iOS`

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry about that - wasn't sure, that was why it was just a comment :( Maybe quote the whole thing?